# ce_cashflow table alternate in oracle fusion cloud

Tags: oracle-fusion-middleware, oracle-sql-data-modeler, oracle-fusion-apps

I have this query made in EBS which has this table ce_cashflows, now the query has to be migrated to oracle fusion cloud but it seems this table has become obsolete. It has significant role in the query, I am sharing it below. Is there any alternate to this table, early help would be highly appreciated.

I have tried to find these columns in various tables in cash management but no help

```
select cc.CASHFLOW_ID, cc.TRXN_REFERENCE_NUMBER, cba.BANK_ACCOUNT_NUM, cba.BANK_ACCOUNT_NAME, cc.CASHFLOW_DIRECTION, cc.CASHFLOW_CURRENCY_CODE, cc.CASHFLOW_AMOUNT, cc.DESCRIPTION, cc.CLEARED_DATE, cc.CASHFLOW_DATE, cc.ACTUAL_VALUE_DATE from ce_cashflows cc , CE_BANK_ACCOUNTS CBA, ce_payment_transactions cpt where 1=1 and cc.CASHFLOW_STATUS_CODE = 'CREATED' and cc.CASHFLOW_BANK_ACCOUNT_ID = cba.BANK_ACCOUNT_ID and cc.TRXN_REFERENCE_NUMBER = cpt.TRXN_REFERENCE_NUMBER and cpt.TRXN_STATUS_CODE = 'SETTLED' order by 2
```

Comment: select  cc.CASHFLOW_ID,
        cc.TRXN_REFERENCE_NUMBER,
        cba.BANK_ACCOUNT_NUM,
        cba.BANK_ACCOUNT_NAME,
        cc.CASHFLOW_DIRECTION,
        cc.CASHFLOW_CURRENCY_CODE,
        cc.CASHFLOW_AMOUNT,
        cc.DESCRIPTION,
        cc.CLEARED_DATE,
        cc.CASHFLOW_DATE,
        cc.ACTUAL_VALUE_DATE
from    ce_cashflows cc ,
        CE_BANK_ACCOUNTS CBA,
        ce_payment_transactions cpt
where  1=1
and     cc.CASHFLOW_STATUS_CODE = 'CREATED'
and     cc.CASHFLOW_BANK_ACCOUNT_ID = cba.BANK_ACCOUNT_ID
and    cc.TRXN_REFERENCE_NUMBER = cpt.TRXN_REFERENCE_NUMBER

Comment: Please [edit] the code into your question as a [code block]. It's very hard to read in a comment, and comments can be deleted at any time for any reason.